# Can anyone explain why NO-OP slide is used in shelllcoding?

Tags: shellcode

An example where NO-OP slide is a **must** for the exploit to work would be really helpful.

Comment: The [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP_slide) article seems to explain it well, and has some references. It also seems to be called a "NOP slide".

Comment: Really it is not for shellcoding, it is for exploiting. And it is useful when you don't know where is the shellcode but know aproximately you know where it is. So you can add nop before the shellcode and when you jump to that zone, your shellcode will executed.

Answer (score 0):

An example of when it is a must is when you want an exploit to be portable when targeting a non-ASLR enabled executable/system. Consider a local privilege escalation exploit where you return to shellcode on the stack. Because the stack holds the environment, the shellcode on the stack will be at slightly different offsets from the top of the stack when executing from within different users' shells, or on different systems. By prefixing the shellcode with, for example, 64k nop instructions, you provide a large margin of error for the stack address since your code will execute the same whether you land on the first nop or the last one.

Using nops is generally not as useful when targeting ASLR enabled systems since data sections will be mapped in entirely different areas of memory